# Sitecore Helix custom database: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sitecore, connection-string

In my Sitecore Helix environment, I am trying to setup a custom database or at least setup a custom table.

In the following route:
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\habitat.dev.local\App_Config I've added the following line to my ConnectionStrings.config`:

```
<add name="RulesDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.RulesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.RulesDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.RulesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\RulesDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I load in the page, the following error appears:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

This also happens if I am only calling the `database.Connection.Open();` method. I've been trying to find solutions, but I can't manage to fix it. I want to push information into a Database or just a custom Table inside my Sitecore environment.

Comment: can you connect to sql from sql server management studio?

Comment: Create a _test-db-connection.udl_ file in File Explorer, then open it by double-click and test connection to your SQL server first. Once the connection via .udl-file is successful you can adjust your config settings accordingly.